# Problem with Baking Normals in blender

Tags: node-editor, normals, baking

[image]
From the image you can see the render looks great but every time I try to bake normals it looks yellowish like the image, can someone tell me what am doing wrong,or if there is another way to bake bump as normals in blender,thanks and also there are no doubles or inverted normals or overlapping meshes thanks

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the normal map. What kind of result were you expecting?

Comment: Less yellow more blue

Comment: High frequency details result in less blue color. If the normal texture works correctly when applied as normal map, then it's absolutely fine.

Comment: Seriously I had no idea thanks

Comment: It works thanks should have applied it first